# VBA Access: Change bound fields through code without write conflicts?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-access

The issue I'm having is that many of the form controls trigger events that make changes to other fields bound to the form which results in a write conflict. I have tried placing `If Me.Dirty Then Me.Dirty = False` to save any changes from user interaction with the form, but I still receive the write conflict regardless or where it is placed.

For example, this will result in a write conflict:

```
Me!pnls_rte_profiles_id = Me!pr_rte
Me.Dirty = False
```

I'm using MS Access 2019 with a rather large database. The forms record set comes from 12 different tables linked through an ODBC connector. Each table has a primary key and a timestamp, but the timestamps aren't pulled as a part of the query for the recordset.

Comment: I'm still unclear on the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try binding the form to a view-model.  That is add a code module with a bunch of public functions like GetMyvalue, SetMyvalue, CalculatemyValue. then bind the form to the viewmodel by replacing calls to other form controls with calls to the viewmodel.  Here is a recent example I gave:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68717654/manipulate-column-expression-formulas-in-multiple-access-2016-queries/68724127#68724127

Comment: Don't really understand issue. I routinely have event behind one control edit another field on form during data entry.

Comment: Instead of `Dirty`, try `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` to save changes.

Comment: And why would two fields have the same data? Usually, a form does data entry/edit for only one table. Are you trying to edit multiple tables with one form?

Comment: @June7 There are 12 tables that are joined together for the query that this form is using as it's record source, so the example is setting a value from one table to another.

Comment: @KostasK. `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord` still causes the write conflict

Comment: I have run the record source query through DBeaver and tried updating the values. Only the main table can have it's values updated, if I try update a joined table I get an error such as  **Can't update attribute 'pnls_rte_profiles_id' - attributes of key 'VIRTUAL_PK' are missing in result set**. So the issue seems to lie in the query itself. Which is 12 different tables joined pulling hundreds of columns.

Comment: I fixed the issue that stopped the query from being updatable. I forgot to include the primary keys of the other tables in the select statement, however the write conflict on the Access side of things is still an issue.

Comment: The issue seems to stem from setting the value to equal what it already is. So setting `Me!pnls_rte_profiles_id = 11` while it already is 11 causes the conflict but `Me!pnls_rte_profiles_id = 12` while it's set to 11 does not. I could check that it's a new value getting set but I feel this shouldn't be necessary?

Comment: Bizarre. Never encountered that. If checking gets past the issue, do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED:**

So I found the issue stemmed from 2 places.

1. I forgot to include the other tables primary keys in my SELECT query.
2. Updating a records value to what it already was caused an issue with the MySQL ODBC connector.

The fix to 2:

1. Open the ODBC manager and configure the connector.
2. Under the Connection tab check **Allow big result sets**
3. Under the Cursors/Results tab check **Return matched rows instead of affected rows**
4. Relink tables in MS Access

[Credit: here](https://loeblcomservices.com/ms-access-mysql-odbc-write-conflict-error-2/)

Hopefully this helps others avoid days of struggling like I did.